# Syntax highlight inside string in Razor View

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have to pass some html code inside a model of a partial view:

```
@Html.Partial("Widgets/_MetroTile", new GraphLiveDto
{
    FrontSlide = @"<h5 class='no-margin semi-bold p-b-5'>Apple Inc.</h5>
                <p class='no-margin text-black hint-text'>NASDAQ : AAPL - NOV 01 8:40 AM ET</p>
                <h3 class='semi-bold text-white'><i class='fa fa-sort-up small text-white'></i> 0.15 (0.13%)</h3>
                <p><span class='text-black'>Open</span> <span class='m-l-20 hint-text'>117.52</span></p>",

    BackSlide = @"<h5 class='no-margin semi-bold p-b-5'>Apple Inc.</h5>
                <p class='no-margin text-black hint-text'>NASDAQ : AAPL - NOV 01 8:40 AM ET</p>
                <h3 class='semi-bold text-white'><i class='fa fa-sort-up small text-white'></i> 0.15 (0.13%)</h3>
                <p><span class='text-black'>Open</span> <span class='m-l-20 hint-text'>117.52</span></p>"
})
```

The problem is this approach is quite ugly. I would like to know if there is a way to get syntax highlighting in this code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are reading the strings(markup) from a table  or somewhere. rite ? I don't think that is ugly. Why do you think otherwise ?

Comment: No, you can't get syntax highlighting inside strings.